# Existence of a measure on intersection of two given measure spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Given two measure spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_i, \mu_i)$, and $\mu_i$ are finite measure for $i=1,2$ .  Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{\mathcal{F}_1\cup\mathcal{F}_2\}$.

What are sufficient and necessary conditions for the existence of a measure $v$ on $\mathcal{F}$ which satisfies: for any $ A\in \mathcal{F}_1, B\in \mathcal{F}_2$ such that
$v(A)=\mu_1(A), v(B)=\mu_2(B)$.

A necessary condition would be for any set $ A\in \mathcal{F}_1, B\in \mathcal{F}_2$, if $A\subset B$ then $\mu_1(A)\leq \mu_2(B)$. Would this condition be sufficient for the existence?